# Volume: Disk method

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose the curve $y=(x+9)^{1/2}$ from $(0,3)$ to $(7,4)$ is rotated about the axis $x=-5$. Write an integral with respect to $y$ representing the area of the resulting surface of revolution.

$S=\int _c^d\:2\pi y\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2}dy$

$S=\int _3^4\:2\pi y\sqrt{1+\left(2y\right)^2}dy$

Okay, I made some corrections. Would this be the correct set up for the problem?

Comment: Wait.. you want the area of the surface of revolution, not the volume. So you picked the wrong method.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are correct that the radius is wrong.  As you are revolving around $x=-5$, the radius of a point $(a,b)$ is $a+5$

To get the volume by disks, you would integrate $\int_{y_1}^{y_2} \pi r^2 dy=\int_3^4 \pi (x+5)^2dy$.  Note that your limits correspond to one $x$ coordinate and one $y$ coordinate.  They certainly need to be in the same direction.

Finally, you are looking for the surface area, not the volume, so need a different formula.

After corrections:  You now have an arc length formula, which is $\int 2\pi r ds$, but your value for $r$ is wrong. Instead of $y$ it should be $x+5$, just as discussed above.  You need to express that in terms of $y$ and you are there.

Comment: Thanks, for pointing that out. I made changes, is my set up for the problem correct now?